How does the crystalline structure influence the strength of neodymium magnets?
community. I have been researching neodymium magnets for a project and would like to understand better how their crystalline structure contributes to their magnetic strength. While I know these magnets are composed of neodymium, iron, and boron, and possess a tetragonal crystalline structure, I am unclear on how this specifically contributes to their high coercivity and magnetic remanence.
Additional Details:
I’ve read that the tetragonal arrangement of their atoms provides a unique magnetic anisotropy that helps maintain the alignment of magnetic moments even in the presence of strong external fields.
I've tried to relate this to the theory of magnetic domains that I learned in classes, but I would like a more detailed explanation of how this structure affects their properties at the atomic level.
What I’ve Tried:
I have reviewed various articles and textbooks on magnetism and magnetic materials, but many do not delve deeply into the direct impact of the crystalline structure on the specific magnetic properties of neodymium magnets.
Could someone provide me with a more detailed explanation or direct me to resources where I can find this information?

This might help, though it isn't specifically about neodymium. MAGNETS: How Do They Work?
